# Ubuntu randomly not detecting USB devices and networking randomly not working?

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, usb, 16.04, windows-10

Ok so this is the first time this has ever happened to me after installing Ubuntu on many laptops.  Basically I am dual booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 and everything has been working fine and well.  Iv'e been using Windows a bit more lately which had me not use Ubunut for about two weeks.  Today I decided to use Ubuntu however when I first logged in my Logitech wireless mouse wasn't detected.  It was a bit strange since it has always worked with both windows and ubuntu. I didn't think much of it so I continued using the laptop with the built in mousepad.  When I logged in the first thing that popped up was that networking was activated but it wasn't detecting any networks which seemed strange.  A few moments later I plugged in my external hard drive and it didn't detect it.  I tried a few flash drives and no luck. The final things that randomly stopped working are the function keys which serve as shortcuts for volume, brightness etc. At this point I was just thinking a reboot should do the trick but nope, I rebooted four time and no luck. Perhaps I need to reinstall the drivers but it's really weird since it has been working perfectly until now.

What do you guys think?

[Notes]

Everything I mentioned is working in Windows 10 so I don't think it's hardware related.

My Laptop specs if needed:

Toshiba Satellite C55D-B5102
AMD A8-6410 APU
12GB DDR3 RAM
1TB Hard Drive

[UPDATE]

Adding to the networking issue I have tried to use a wired connection via ethernet in order to connect to the internet but it's not even detecting that.  I have also noticed that Ubuntu is running extremely slow which is a first. 
I have tried going into the Ubuntu advanced options in the boot grub and I have tried using the "activate networking" option but i'm getting a network error. This is becoming quite stressful and I hope there is a solution or I will just have to reinstall Ubuntu which I hope I don't resorte to...

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem thanks to some help from the Ubuntu facebook group.

Basically i had to use the command

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

This is to remove packages installed by other packages which are no longer needed.

This fixed every problem that I was having.  I hope this helps anybody who is having this problem.