# Ubuntu randomly not detecting USB devices and networking randomly not working

Tags: networking, drivers, dual-boot, usb, 22.04

I am dual booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu 22.04. I'm currently attempting to completely transition from Windows but have ran into a weird issue.

Although I'm running a new Ubuntu and different hardware from the link mentioned below The issue seems to align closely with [Ubuntu randomly not detecting USB devices and networking randomly not working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/801504/ubuntu-randomly-not-detecting-usb-devices-and-networking-randomly-not-working)

I've attempted trying the recommendation in that thread and only succeeded in removing some of Nvidia software that caused some display glitches.

Sometimes when I reboot I'll have access to usb or networking but can't seem to have everything working at once.

My motherboard is Asus Sabertooth X79 running Dual Geforce GTX 770's and I believe Intel 3930K CPU.

Running lsusb I notice alot of my USB devices seem to be sharing the same USB Bus, not sure if that's an issue just something I thought worth noting.

Are there any logs I can dig into that might give me a clear indication or a thread I can pull on for why devices in certain cases don't get initialized? It's making an otherwise pleasant transition a little frustrating.

Comment: Logs: all are in `/var/logs/`. Genereally I would suggest to look at those that changed (`ls -ltr` the files at the end are the newest) and do a `grep ERROR {file}`.  Important: find a common action. Does this happen after you used windows? Does it happen on a reboot or cold boot? Do you have autosuspend active? (no idea if this still works on 22.04: https://askubuntu.com/questions/526082/two-usb-ports-stopped-working)

Comment: Also a suggestion: remove the non-essential parts from the question. I myself often skip questions that start with your 1st sentence as it takes me time to read where I would rather read what the problem is ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. These issue doesn't happen on Windows. I've removed the fluff from the beginning of my post. I'll try both of these suggestions when I have access to my machine. I'm fairly certain one of the usb devices (https://www.jmicron.com/file/download/1002/JMS583_Product+Brief.pdf) with the latest firmware has autosuspend active. That's the main device that seems to rarely work either upon boot and never seems to initialize after disconnecting / reconnecting on the fly.